# prove that $f$ is nowhere differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$$f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left({\frac{3}{4}}\right)^{j}\sin(4^jx)$$
How can I prove that $f$ is nowhere differentiable? I know that the $j$th summands are all continuous and bounded by $\left({\frac{3}{4}}\right)^{j}$ so by Weierstrass test, $f$ converges uniformly and therefore $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Notice that sin(-)^(3 4j). Then for some point  there exists > such that they cancel out due to the summing. I'm sorry that to be my comment to your original solution but I messed up and it out as an edit. Feel free to change it bakc or ask any questions. Sorry agai, but off today;